# Python3. Find values of array in values dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

I have two lists.

> List all_text - the first value is the key, the second meaning is a
>   set of words.
>
> List keyword_list - list of keywords I want to find in a set of words
>   all_text.

My code shows all values from list all_text.

I want to get the following results:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Z1234': ['earth'], 'Z1207': ['north']})
```

How to fix my code below?

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
all_text = [['Z1234', 'earth total surface area land'], ['Z1207', 'first 
north university']]
keyword_list = ['earth', 'north']

dictions = defaultdict(list)
for key, sentence in all_text:
    dictions[key].extend(sentence.split())

result = defaultdict(list)
for x in dictions.values():
    for i in x:
        for y in keyword_list:
            if i in y:
                result[key].extend(x)
print(result)

>>defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Z1207': ['first', 'north', 'university', 
'earth', 'total', 'surface', 'area', 'land']})
```

Comment: The value of key in the line `result[key].extend(x)` looks like it is probably just whatever is left over form the `for key, sentence in all_text:` loop. Instead do `for key, x in dictions.items():`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
from collections import defaultdict

all_text = [['Z1234', 'earth total surface area land'],
            ['Z1207', 'first north university']]
keyword_list = ['earth', 'north']

keyword_set = set(keyword_list)

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in all_text:
    for w in set(v.split()) & keyword_set:
        d[k].append(w)

# defaultdict(list, {'Z1207': ['north'], 'Z1234': ['earth']})
```

**Explanation**

- [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with no argument separates a string in to a list of words by whitespace.
- `&` is alternative syntax for [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set%20intersection#set-types-set-frozenset) intersection.

Comment: Nice use of set operations

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quit easy in python with `zip`. Please refer the code below and check if this is the exact same thing you want:

```
all_text = [['Z1234', 'earth total surface area land'], ['Z1207', 'first north university']]
keyword_list = ['earth', 'north']
finaldict = {}
for i,item in zip(keyword_list, all_text):
    finaldict[item[0]] = i
print(finaldict)
```

Comment: Sorry, it meant `keyword_list`. Let me fix it quickly.

Comment: But isn't the whole point that you don't know (to begin with) which word is in which list? `zip` only works if this ordering is guaranteed..